# How to print a map that uses the google maps API on a PDF using Rotativa?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, pdf, rotativa

I am using Rotativa in order to obtain a PDF containing information that is previously shown on a Modal, nevertheless, when the user clicks on the button to obtain the PDF, this one does not contain a map that uses the google maps API, is there any way to solve this?

Here is the Modal that is previously shown to the user with the information:

[image: MODAL]

This is the PDF, notice that PDF is not printing the map and it should be there:

[image: PDF]

Here is my code:

*Front-end code*

```
             var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], {
            center: { lat: 19.397, lng: -99.144 },
            zoom: 10
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(19.397, -99.144),
            map: map,
            title: ""
        });

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);


        marker.setPosition(LatLng);
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setCenter(LatLng);
        map.setZoom(18);



        /*Poligonos*/
        var rut = $("#txt_Ruta").val();
        var ced = $("#txt_Cedis").val();
        var frecu = CosasModal.orden.Frecuencia;

        var jqxhr = $.post("/Poligonos/ObtenerPoligono", { "Ruta": rut, "Frecuencia": frecu, "Cedis": ced },
            function (data) {
                if (data.status == "OK") {
                    var Poligono = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        path: data.coordinates,
                        geodesic: true,
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                        strokeWeight: 2
                    });

                    Poligono.setMap(map);

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: "Ruta " + rut + "<br>Frecuencia: " + frecu + "<br>Cedis: " + ced
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(Poligono, 'click', function (event) {

                        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                        infowindow.open(map);
                    });

                    var points = Poligono.getPath().getArray();
                    for (var n = 0; n < points.length; n++) {
                        bounds.extend(points[n]);
                    }
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                }
            });
        jqxhr.fail(function () {
            //alert("Error de comunicación con el servidor.");
            swal("Error", "Error de comunicación con el servidor.", "error");
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        map.panToBounds(bounds);
        /*fin poligonos*/
```

*Rotativa code* (imagine that you receive idOrden variable)

```
   var pdf = new ActionAsPdf("ModalPedidosPdfView", new { idOrden = idOrden })
            {
                FileName = "ReporteOrdenIndividual" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "_" + idOrden
            };

            return pdf;
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for Rotativa? Couldn't find any. Did you try printing background images? There usually is such an option in PDF generators.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using [Select.pdf](https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf-api/) instead of Rotativa